# Make background yellow for correct answer in listivew

Tags: android

A user selects an answer from a series of options in a listview. After submitting (right or wrong) I intend to highlight the correct answer in the list view.

I thought I had it figured:

```
 // get the position from the array we fed into the list view that has the correct answer    
int correct = curquestion.GetIndexOfCorrectAnswer();
// set that item's background to yellow
lView.getChildAt(correct).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

I've discovered though through watching this run, and reading other people's posts herem that getChildAt doesn't provide a reliable result- sometimes it appears to pick a random child to set yellow. Any suggestions on other approaches?

Comment: Incase someone suggests this, sadly I already tried it: ((View)lView.getItemAtPosition(correct)).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

Comment: Are there more elements in the `lView`, than you can put on screen without scrolling the `lView`?

Comment: Note that if you have more elements in the `lView` than you can put on screen without scrolling, the element that goes off the screen while scrolling will be recycled (if you built your `lView` correctly). What I mean is that no matter how many elements you have in the adapter backing up this listView, the listView will always have the same number of childs. And that can trick you, because of the model you built to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter position of list item at which you want to set color:

```
 adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
 adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
 listView.invalidate();
```

and in adapter class:

// change the row color based on selected state

```
if(selectedPos == position){
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
 }else{
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not familiar with setselectedposition, it doesn't appear to be in my ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; that I use to populate my list with, will do some reading.

Comment: you can override, getView method, using arrayadater too.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `OnItemClickListener` abstract class ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)), which you should register with the `ListView` object with the `setOnItemClickListener()` method. And, in the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` callback method you can test if the user selected the right answer, and there you have the view the user clicked on, so you can color it yellow.

Comment: good thought, but all that would do is tell me if the one they have clicked on is the correct answer. If one of the other options is the correct answer I still wouldn't be able to find it.

Comment: Then you should use another model for your problem (create a custom view for example, which is backed up by a better model for solving this problem).

Comment: My real example is using a custom view (which also suffers the sample problem) I simplified for the purposes of getting some suggestions. Anyone have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Set onSubmit button click following code
Have correct integer variable as field of activity initialized with -1;

```
// get the position from the array we fed into the list view that has the correct answer    
correct = curquestion.GetIndexOfCorrectAnswer();
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

and in getView of adapter do following:

```
if(position==correct){
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested I'll post my final code here:

```
        lView.setEnabled(false);
        btnsubmit.setEnabled(true);
        int correct = curquestion.GetIndexOfCorrectAnswer();

        // tell the system the correct answer
        adapters.SetSelectedPosition(correct);
        //adapters.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The above code is called on the activity, the below is the custom class for the handler. The other xml pieces you could probably figure.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.walpdroid2.R;

public class QuizDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Answer>
{
Answer [] objects = null;
Context checkcontext;
int _selectedIndex;
int checkedviewresourceid;
int uncheckedviewresourceid;

int selectedPos = -1;

public QuizDataAdapter(Context checkcontext, int checkresourceid, int uncheckresourceid, Answer[] objects)
{
    super(checkcontext, checkresourceid, objects);
    this.checkedviewresourceid = checkresourceid;
    this.uncheckedviewresourceid = uncheckresourceid;
    this.checkcontext = checkcontext;
    this.objects = objects;

}

public int getCount()
{
    return this.objects.length;
}

public Answer getItem(int position)
{
    return this.objects[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public void setSelected(int index) {

      if (index == -1) {
        // unselected
      }
      else {
        // selected index...
      }

      _selectedIndex = index;

      // notify the model that the data has changed, need to update the view
      notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void SetSelectedPosition(int pos)
{
    this.selectedPos = pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    CheckedTextView holder = null;

    if((row == null) || (selectedPos == position))
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)checkcontext).getLayoutInflater();

        if(selectedPos == position)
        {
            row = inflater.inflate(checkedviewresourceid, parent, false);
            holder = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.CheckRow);
        }
        else
        {
            row = inflater.inflate(uncheckedviewresourceid, parent, false);
            holder = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.UnCheckRow);                
        }

        holder.setText(objects[position].getAnswer());
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CheckedTextView)row.getTag();
        holder.setText(objects[position].getAnswer());
    }


    return row;
}
```

}